# Matrices above matrix in LaTeX

Tags: equations, matrices

Ok..How to put matrices above matrix when you work with complex equations? I have matrices, such as:

[image]

I was able to wrote equation in the LaTeX first two matrices on bottom, but the 1x1 matrix on top seems unreal to write in LaTeX.

Here is my code:

```
\begin{bmatrix}
  (\textbf{u}_{1}\textbf{v}_{1}) & \cdots & (\textbf{u}_{1}\textbf{v}_{n}) \\
  \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
  (\textbf{u}_{n}\textbf{v}_{1}) & \cdots & (\textbf{u}_{n}\textbf{v}_{n})
\end{bmatrix}
```

Any suggestions regarding that matrix on very top shown in the attached picture?

Comment: Would be using `tikz` environments an option? This is completely overkilled, but an example [as this one](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/matrix-multiplication/) could give you some ideas.

Answer (score 5):

With some manual adjusting:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}%[border=2mm,prewiev]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}

    \begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 ~   & \,  
    \begin{bmatrix}
 \mathbf{v}_{1}  & \\  \quad\cdots\quad & \\   \mathbf{v}_{n}
    \end{bmatrix}                   \\
%
    \begin{bmatrix}
u_{1} \\    \vdots \\   u_{n}
    \end{bmatrix}
    &
    \begin{bmatrix} 
\mathbf{u}_{1}\mathbf{v}_{1}    & \cdots & \mathbf{u}_{1}\mathbf{v}_{n} \\
\vdots                          & \ddots & \vdots                       \\
\mathbf{u}_{n}\mathbf{v}_{1}    & \cdots & \mathbf{u}_{n}\mathbf{v}_{n}
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution, with `\blkarray`:

```
\documentclass{article}%[border=2mm,prewiev]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut}

\newcommand\topstrut[1][1.2ex]{\setlength\bigstrutjot{#1}{\bigstrut[t]}}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{blockarray}{clcr}
\begin{block}{c[!{\mspace{-3.2mu}}lcr!{\!}]}
& \mspace{3.2mu}\mathbf{v}_{1} & \cdots & \mathbf{v}_{n}\,\\
\end{block}
\begin{block}{[c][lcl]}
u_1 & \mathbf{u}_{1}\mathbf{v}_{1} & \cdots & \mathbf{u}_{1}\mathbf{v}_{n}\topstrut[1ex] \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
u_n & \mathbf{u}_{n}\mathbf{v}_{1} & \cdots & \mathbf{u}_{n}\mathbf{v}_{n}\\[0.9ex]
\end{block}
\end{blockarray} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But with  some manual adjusting as well.

Comment: @Clément: I didn't c!aim there was none. One of them seems to be inherent to `blockarray`: the brackets are slightly too short. The other is specific to this problem: vertically adjusting the right-hand side matrices.

Comment: No, of course, but at first I thought there was no manual tweaking in your solution. So it was more a comment to myself, because I looked for a solution without manual adjustment, and couldn't find any. Neither could any of us, as it seems. Thanks for the additional clarification.